# Alinhamento de imagens dentro do box

Tags: html, css

Eu possuo uma 'caixa' onde imagens são carregadas, em todos os carregamentos o box tem o mesmo tamanho, esse tamanho é:

```
width:700px; 
height:575px
```

Porém nem todas as imagens possuem o mesmo tamanho, ou seja, os tamanhos delas variam podendo alcançar as medidas máximas do box ao qual ela é carregada.

Exemplo:

```
<div style="width:700px; height:575px">
  <img src="IMAGEM A SER CARREGADA" style="max-width:700px; max-height:575px">
</div>
```

Sabendo então que o tamanho da imagem sempre será variável, como eu posso deixar essas imagens centralizadas na vertical e na horizontal dentro da caixa onde ela foi carregada?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma possibilidade é usar background para fazer isto:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.imagem {
    width: 700px;
    height: 575px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: #fff url('imagem.png') no-repeat center;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="imagem"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Obs:
O border é só para mostrar a borda para testar.
Se não achar a imagem irá preencher com branco.
Se a imagem for maior que o tamanha da caixa, será cortada (pode redimensionar também se preferir). Se for menor será centralizada na div.

Answer (score 0):

Da uma olhada nesse artigo do Smashing Magazine:
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/

Aqui fica um exemplo online:
http://codepen.io/shshaw/details/gEiDt